# Pycharm does not identify a colon

Tags: dictionary, pycharm

I am new to python and I am using Pycharm as my environment.
I am working with dictionaries now.
For some reason, Pycharm cannot recognize my : when I used it in a dictionary.
Weird thing is that it recognized it for previous keys and values..
Any help?

[image]

Comment: It is not an error of syntaxis, missing comma ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the **colon**. You are missing the **comma** (,) which separates the elements in the dictionary.

```
pan = {'name':'poguaa','age':12}
```

will do.

Comment: please consider up voting the answer if it helped u